# Convex optimization max/min with constant

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, cvx

I am trying to determine a battery's state of charge (SOC) $b(t)$ from generation and load curves, $g(t)$ and $l(t)$. The recursive expression for the SOC is:

$b(t+1) = min[C, max(0, b(t) + g(t) - l(t))]$

where $C$ is battery capacity. Is there any way to write this as a convex optimization problem? Of course, $b(t)$ can be found iteratively, but I later want to optimize over $g(t)$ and $l(t)$. I know the nesting of $min()$ and $max()$ is not convex in general, but here since I am taking $min()$ and $max()$ with a constant, it seems it should be possible. If I am misunderstanding convexity for this case, I would like to understand why.

The goal would be to put $g(t)$ and $l(t)$ into CVX and determine the vector $b(t)$.

Comment: What are you trying to optimize over?

Comment: I suppose this is like a feasibility problem. I am optimizing over the values [b(1)....b(T)] such that the above min/max expression holds for every b(t) in (b(1)...b(T)). The reason to cast this as an optimization is because later I will be trying to find some optimal l(t) and g(t) such that b(t) defined as above has certain properties.

Comment: You might want to look into dynamic programming (see, for example, Bertsekas "Dynamic programming and optimal control" for an introduction).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not going to be convex.